# What is the maximal size of a .cap file to be loaded on a sim card

Tags: applet, javacard, sim-card

I am trying to load a CAP file (an applet binary) onto a SIM card. I face some problems when loading it! I would like to know if the size of CAP file can be the reason. If yes, what is the maximal size?

Comment: Could you please add some more info about your problems? We would appreciate communication log, the size of your CAP file etc.

Comment: My .cap size is (~ 32000 octets)

Comment: the error message is : use condition not satisfied

Comment: Are you authenticated to the security domain? Are you sure there is no package with the same AID already present on SIM?

Comment: What tool do you use for uploading?

Comment: Yes, I verified all information that you quote, i am using a gemalto tool

Comment: In the first step please confirm that you can install smaller applets on your card using _Gemalto Tool_ to make us sure that you didn't forgot any authentication level and card is not locked or something?

Comment: And about the maximum size of your cap file : Yes, It can be the reason of error but it depend on your card type. If the CAP file need more RAM or EEPROM than the capacity of the card in the installation process, you face this kind of errors. I had a similar experience with big CAP files but I'm not sure about that. I'll retry and make you update about my tries. You please check my previous comment and also give us some details about your card.

Comment: And also please make us sure that you didn't break the _mehtods_, _class instances_ and _arrays_ limitation in your applet. For example you can't have an array with greater than 32767 component, a class instance with greater than 255 fields and so on ... (mentioned in JCVM specifications)

Comment: You can write a simple applet to get the free EEPROM size of your card first (use api: `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)`), if the size is less than _32000 octets_, the cap can not be loaded. This comment consider if the EEPROM size is not enough. If the size is enough, other reasons could be considered;

Comment: As normal cap file, the number of components/classes did not exceed the number of virtual machine's limits. Unless your package is used to test the limits parameters of the virtual machine.

Comment: @DGz Please update us about your tries :)

Comment: I think that the raison was the applet size, I succeeded to load it when i deleted some code ligne and reduced the size to 29000 Octets.

Comment: Did you delete any special method or class? Or those was some simple unused variables?

Comment: Firstly, i loaded the original applet into my sim without any problem, and then i added some fonctionnalities to the original applet , By consequence the size increased and I could not download ! after reading your comments i reduce the size by deleting some code ligne and some fonctionalties , the applet is downloadable now but it not contain all the fonctionalities that I want, i hope it's clear, i still available for other questions

Answer (score 0):

And manufacturers of card and javacard version.